# @Autowired not working for interface

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, annotations, autowired

I am trying all the solutions from Google from last 4 days. but not working.

I am trying to autowire below Interface -

```
@Qualifier("roleAccessRepository")
@Repository
public interface RoleAccessRepository extends BaseJPACrudRepository<RoleAccess, Long> {
```

in PermissionEvaluator in following way.But its not working.

```
 @Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES, value = "prototype")
public class PermissionEvaluator implements           org.springframework.security.access.PermissionEvaluator
 {

  @Autowired
  RoleAccessRepository roleAccessRepository;
```

..........

Giving me error -

```
      Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: net.pa
ger.lrs.sql.db.RoleAccessRepository net.pager.lrs.security.PermissionEvaluator.roleAccessRepository;
 nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying
bean of type [net.pager.lrs.sql.db.RoleAccessRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 b
ean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springf
```

But Repository defined in the same package and autowired in service class are working good.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class AccountService extends BaseCrudService<Account> {

/** The account db. */
@Autowired
private AccountRepository accountDB;

}
```

My security.xml is as follows - which has base package net.pager.lrs which is parent directory.

```
<bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="net.pager.lrs.security.PermissionEvaluator">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
```

Please help me.

Comment: Your `PermissionEvaluator` is an `@Component` and is defined in XML you have multiple instances of the `PermissionEvaluator` due to component-scanning. Remove the `@Component` to not have it detected. Also why is everything prototype scoped? Singleton should be fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for instant reply. Actually for PermissionEvaluator I added it as workaround. and Prototype too. Will try removing it.

Comment: I tried removing @Component for PermissionEvaluator and removing Prototype scope. But still getting same error while I do   @Autowired(required = true)
  RoleAccessRepository roleAccessRepository;

Comment: I feel that you might have problem with context hierarchy. Where is your component scan defined and where is your `<bean id="permissionEvaluator">` defined? (btw. `required = true` default for `@Autowired`). Also if you could format that stack trace that would be fine.

Comment: @pavel horal - Hi , both are defined in the same xml file one after other.    <context:component-scan base-package="net.pager.lrs"/>
     <jpa:repositories base-package="net.pager.lrs.sql.db" /> ......

    <bean id="permissionEvaluator" class="net.pager.lrs.security.PermissionEvaluator">
        <constructor-arg index="0">

Comment: Help me understand this. I see the error which says that there is no qualifying bean. Do you have an implementation for the interface RoleAccessRepository  ?

Comment: @dharam Good catch - I didn't even notice that is an interface. The `@Repository` and `@Qualifier` annotation is useless there.

Comment: :) So best of luck with your implementation now.

Comment: This is what my confusion was because it is working all over my project,in all services. I have given example above. In AccountService we are using   @ Autowired  private AccountRepository accountDB; and its defination is     @ Repository
     public interface AccountRepository extends    BaseJPACrudRepository<Account, Long>.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

From the discussions above, I still think that the problem is with not having the concrete implementation of the `Autowired` interfaces. Just for the sake of common sense, if you do not provide an implementation, what will you execute using the reference of the `Autowired` interface.

There is a way where you do not define the implementation, spring can generate proxy beans and autowire, but that is of no use.

You might end up providing an anonymous implementation of the interface as well.

Comment: I have tried that too,by implementing interface and autowired class. But was getting same error. as below                            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: net.pa
ger.lrs.sql.db.RoleAccessRepositoryImpl net.pager.lrs.security.PermissionEvaluator.roleAccessReposit
oryImpl; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set net.pager.lrs.sql.db.Ro
leAccessRepositoryImpl field net.pager.lrs.security.PermissionEvaluator.roleAccessRepositoryImpl to
$Proxy55

Comment: "There is a way where you do not define the implementation, spring can generate proxy beans and autowire, but that is of no use." why do you think it, could you please let me know the reason?